# best way to get the last inserted record in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi all I having a Identity column and a Computed primary key column in my table I need to get the last inserted record immediately after inserting the record in to database, So I have written the following queries can some one tell which is the best one to choose

```
SELECT
t.[StudentID]
FROM
[tbl_Student] t
WHERE
t.ID = IDENT_CURRENT('tbl_Student')
```

The other is using `MAX` as follows

```
Select 
MAX(StudentID) 
from tbl_Student
```

From the above two queries which is the best one to choose.

Comment: You *probably* want the record that you just inserted, which is not necessarily the same as "the last inserted record".

Comment: [IDENT_CURRENT](https://mostafaelmasry.com/2016/05/09/how-to-find-the-last-inserted-record-in-sql-server/) have no limited Scope and it returns the last inserted record generated for a specific table in any session.

Answer (score 5):

MAX and [IDENT_CURRENT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx), according to technet, would behave much the same and both would be equally unreliable.

*"IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by scope and session; it is limited to a specified table. IDENT_CURRENT returns the identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope. For more information, see IDENT_CURRENT (Transact-SQL)."*

Basically, to return the last insert within the current scope, regardless of any potential triggers or inserts / deletes from other sessions, you should use SCOPE_IDENTITY. Of course, that's assuming you're running the query in the same scope as the actual insert in the first place. :)

If you are, you also have the alternative of simply using OUTPUT clause to get the inserted ID values into a table variable / temporary table, and select from there.

Answer (score 2):

The original answer, where my assumptions about `IDENT_CURRENT`where wrong.

Use the first one. `IDENT_CURRENT` should give you the last item for the current connection. If someone else would insert another student concurrently `IDENT_CURRENT` will give you the correct value for both clients, while `MAX` might give you a wrong value.

EDIT:

As it was mentioned in the other answer `IDENT_CURRENT`and `MAX`are equally unreliable in case of concurrent usage. I would still go for `IDENT_CURRENT` but if you want to get the last identity used by the current scope or session you can use the functions `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY`. This [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) explains the detailed differences between `IDENT_CURRENT`, `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.